# Can our ISP view our Browsing history?

Tags: censorship

Can our Internet service provider know our browsing history?
Does the server know what sites we are browsing?

Comment: Are you asking about while you're using Tor? Or without using Tor?

Answer (score 1):

By default, your Internet service provider (ISP) is capable and willing to record your browsing history. Sometimes it's even obligated, under local/federal regulations, to do so. However, you may have some options to limit that. Some of these options are: Tor, Tor browser, Tails, JAP/JonDo, virtual private network (VPN), and web proxy services. Each of these services limit the information that your ISP can record. If you have no other concern than your ISP recording your activity, you maybe able to use any of them to limit the amount information recorded by your ISP about your browsing activity. If you have additional concerns beside and beyond your ISP, then you need to list your options. One by one, compare what each service can provide to you, and under what circumstances. If you have additional concerns, please state them, and I will edit the answer to address your concerns. Happy surfing.